# C linker "-TLink.ld"

Tags: c

I've been trying to link a "link. ld" file for a while now and I can't get to Mac Os. There would be an alternative to that. Like `"gobjcopy -j. text --set-start 0x7c00 -O binary source. o boot. bin"`. So how can I use my link. ld file with this command, because under Mac 0s `-Tlink.ld` tells me that it doesn't recognize this command `"-T"` Thanks for your help 
Below you will find the source `link.ld`
see you soon.

```
ENTRY(start)
SECTION{

    .text 0x100000:
    {
        code = .; _code = .; __code =.;
        *(.text)
        . = ALIGN(4096);
    }

    .data:
    {
        data = .; _data = .; __data = .;
        *(.data)
        *(.rodata)
        . = ALIGN(4096);
    }

    .bss:{
        bss = .; _bss = .; __bss = .;
        *(.bss)
        . = ALIGN(4096);
    }

    end = .; _end = .; __end =.;
}
```

Comment: You need to mention your target system, compiler, version, environnment, context etc.

Comment: I explain my problem in more detail. I plan to use the script in my first post to generate a specific binary. Under the GNU/Linux operating system, I can easily make my binary. However, the same command on Mac Os does not work: `ld -T link.ld -o Os.bin boot. o`
`ld: unknown option: -T`. so I did a little digging and had as an alternative "gobjcopy" however, I intend to use my script with it.